# Python Get subvalues from flattened list from xml

Tags: python, xml

I'm parsing all of the clinical trial info from the following XML:
https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT00446316?term=imatimib&rank=1?displayxml=true

In the non-XML version (to view it, just remove ?displayxml=true from the URL above), there's a list (specifically, the eligibility criteria) that has numbers and hyphenated sublevels. 
In the XML version, those hyphens are still there, but there's no way to get the sublevels as actual sublevels.

The list entries in question specifically is the following:

```
'7. Adequate organ function including the following:', 
'- Adequate bone marrow reserve:', 
'- Total white blood cell count (WBC) > 3.0 x 109/L', 
'- Platelet count >100 x 109/L', '- Hemoglobin >8 g/dL', 
'- Hepatic:', '- Bilirubin: = 1.25 times the upper limit of normal (ULN)', 
'- Alanine transaminase (ALT): = <5 times the ULN', 
'- Aspartate transaminase (AST): = <5 times the ULN', 
'- Renal: Serum creatinine =< 1.5 times the ULN, or creatinine clearance 
=>60mL/minute as calculated by the standard Cockcroft Gault formula.'
```

Those are are supposed to be part of the same entry (number 7), but aren't. Is there any way to programmatically

a) detect that those subheaders exists and

b) make them all part of the same entry (in some way, doesn't have to be perfect)

Thanks so much.

Comment: Post some python codes showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wWpNiphx

This is the parsing method I'm using. It's using code that works for criteria listings that are either: all numbers, or all hyphens. But no hyphens within numbers...